# Excel: find value in a list, where the value is defined by variables in two different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with variables in two columns. I want to find a value from a third column that matches the criteria in both first columns:

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZHss.png)

The search criteria will be defined dynamically (i.e., the city and direction will change based on another result). I want to do this with a formula and no macro (but that should be possible, I hope ;) ). I tried various INDEX and MATCH formulas, but none gave me the correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XLOOKUP()` would be best in this case. Try-

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(A1:A8=F1)*(B1:B8=G1),C1:C8)
```

You can also use `FILTER()` function.

```
=FILTER(C1:C8,(A1:A8=F1)*(B1:B8=G1))
```

In case of older version of excels you may try `INDEX/MATCH` with array entry by <kbd>**CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**</kbd>

```
=INDEX(C1:C8,MATCH(1,(A1:A8=F1)*(B1:B8=G1)))
```

[image]